# beautifulsoup python getting text value within a href ,

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<a href="allswell/index.html">Oh well Oh well</a>
```

I'm trying to get value "Oh well Oh well"

I can use `tr['href']` to get "allswell/index.html"

but I have try everything text, element .. what do I call this value and how do I get this value from beautifulsoup ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `text` attribute of your element

```
print(tr.text)
```